# android navigation component navigate to fragment in other graph with viewpager2 and bottom navigation

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-viewpager2

I have a four navigation in MainActivity.

home_navigation
(homeFragment ->  homereportFragment)

device_navigation
(devicefragment -> deviceUserFragment -> deviceScanFragment)

and config_navigation, automation_navigation ..

I want to move to deviceUserFragment in homeFragment

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.main.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/slider_main"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_nav" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

private val mOnNavigationItemselectedListener =
    BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.home_navigation -> {
                slider_main.currentItem = 0
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.device_navigation -> {
                slider_main.currentItem = 1
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.automation_navigation -> {
                slider_main.currentItem = 2
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.config_navigation -> {
                slider_main.currentItem = 3
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }


private val onpage = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {

    }

    override fun onPageScrolled(
        position: Int,
        positionOffset: Float,
        positionOffsetPixels: Int
    ) {

    }

    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        bottom_nav.menu.getItem(position).isChecked = true
    }

}




private fun initViewPager() {
    viewpagerAdapter = SliderAdapterMain(this)
    slider_main.apply {
        adapter = viewpagerAdapter
        registerOnPageChangeCallback(onpage)
    }
    bottom_nav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemselectedListener)
}
```

MainActivity code with viewPager2 and bottomnavigation

```
home_reistdevice_button.setOnClickListener {
        activity!!.bottom_nav.selectedItemId = R.id.device_navigation
    }
```

It's button in homeFragment.
But button results deviceFragment.

I tried to add deviceUserFragment in home_navigation graph.
But It doesn't work bottom navigation Item.

I think I should pass value homeFragment to deviceFragment.

So if deiviceFragment get value, navigate to deviceUserFragment as soon as deviceFragment start.

But i don't know how to pass value in bottomnavigation item select.

Somebody tell me how to do it.

Or tell me the best way.

@Edit 2020-09-03
I found a solution.
Solution is onBacklistener adding in ContainerFragmnet

```
class HomeContainerFragment : Fragment() {

private var navController:NavController?=null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_container, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val navHostFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.home_nav_host) as NavHostFragment?

    navController = navHostFragment?.navController

    listenOnBackPressed()


}

private fun listenOnBackPressed(){
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner,callback)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    callback.isEnabled = true
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    callback.isEnabled =false
}
private fun dialog_build(){
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.AlertDialog))
    builder.setTitle("App terminate")
    builder.setMessage("Are you terminating APP?")

    builder.setPositiveButton("terminate") { _, _ ->
        activity?.finishAffinity()
    }
    builder.setNegativeButton("cancel") { _, _ ->

    }

    builder.show()
}

val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(false) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        var backkeytime: Long = 0
        lateinit var toast: Toast

        if(navController?.currentDestination?.id == navController?.graph?.startDestination){
            isEnabled = false
            dialog_build()
            isEnabled = true
        }
        else{
            navController?.navigateUp()
        }

    }
}
```

}

My whole project structure is 1 Activity 4 ContainerFragment(4 navigation)

MainActivity (ViewPager2, BottomNavigation)

- HomeContainerFragment ( FragmentContainerView - home_navigation )

  (in navigation) - HomeFragment
  - HomeReportFragment
  - ..
- DeviceContainerFragment
- ...